# Laravel how to route old urls

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, url-routing

I am using Laravel 4.

I have an old url that needs to be routable. It doesn't really matter what it's purpose is but it exists within the paypal systems and will be called regularly but cannot be changed  (which is ridiculous I know).

I realise that this isn't the format url's are supposed to take in Laravel, but this is the url that will be called and I need to find a way to route it:

> http://domain.com/forum/index.php?app=subscriptions&r_f_g=xxx-paypal

(xxx will be different on every request)

I can't figure out how to route this with laravel, i'd like to route it to the method PaypalController@ipbIpn so i've tried something like this:

```
Route::post('forum/index.php?app=subscriptions&r_f_g={id}-paypal', 'PaypalController@ipbIpn');
```

But this doesn't work, infact I can't even get this to work:

```
Route::post('forum/index.php', 'PaypalController@ipbIpn');
```

But this will:

```
Route::post('forum/index', 'PaypalController@ipbIpn');
```

So the question is how can I route the url, as it is at the top of this question, using Laravel?

For completeness I should say that this will always be a post not a get, but that shouldn't really make any difference to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Route::post('forum/{file}', 'PaypalController@ipbIpn');
```

And then in the controller, use

```
    public function forum($file) {
            $request = Route::getRequest();

            $q = (array) $request->query; // GET
            $parameters = array();
            foreach($q as $key => $pararr) {
                $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $pararr);
            }
    }
```

You can then access the get parameters via e.g.

```
echo $parameters['app'];
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't appear to work, it simply gives a 404 error, like I said in the original question forum/index.php didn't even work, I think there may be a problem with laravel routing files with extensions

Comment: Still doesn't work, it works without the ".php" in the url, just using index, but if it's changed to index.php it comes back with a NotFoundHttpException

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop works for me, are you sure you're doing a post request?

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop have you also correctly linked to the public folder?

Comment: Yes the app is running just fine in every other way. I'm not totally sure why you've used the "forum" method, why would it call that? Surely it would call ipbIpn(). Either way it doesn't call either. Even a simple doesn't work Route::get('forum/{file}', function(){return 'test';}); Does that work for you :S

Comment: Note I used get in that example for ease of testing

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop Have you set your 'url' correctly in the app.php config file? Do you have .htaccess enabled?

Comment: Yes .htaccess is set, this is a complete and working app. I don't fully understanding how it can work for you and not me. Are you telling me that this definitely works for you? http://paste.laravel.com/IKV

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35262/discussion-between-alexander-cogneau-and-freeze-dried-pop)

Answer (score 0):

you can use route redirection to mask and ending .php route ex:

```
Route::get('forum/index', ['uses'=> 'PaypalController@ipbIpn']);
Route::redirect('forum/index.php', 'forum/index');
```